# Sql count condition based on change of value

Tags: sql

So i have a table like this

| Date | test |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |
| 2 | Yes |
| 3 | No |
| 4 | Yes |
| 5 | Yes |
| 6 | No |

And i want the result table like this

| Date | test | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes | 1 |
| 2 | Yes | 1 |
| 3 | No | 2 |
| 4 | Yes | 3 |
| 5 | Yes | 3 |
| 6 | No | 4 |

How to do the sql query? Kinda confused . Thankyou for the help and suggestion

Comment: Can you please share your attempt at resolving this? Have you written any query which is failing or not giving desired results?

Comment: Select test,count(case when test ='Yes' then 0 else 1) as "count" from tabel . Sorry i'm writting via phone

Answer (score 0):

Try Something like this:

```
SELECT t.date, 
       t.test,
       sum(t.r) OVER (ORDER BY t.date)
FROM (
    SELECT DATE,
           test,
           CASE WHEN lag(test) OVER (order by date) IS null Then 1
                WHEN test <> lag(test) OVER (order by date) Then 1
                ELSE 0
           END as r
    FROM tableA
    )t
```

[db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=54eddb9bf7b37c4a37a936270ed0d041)